# VMware Workstation Unrecoverable Error: (vcpu-0)

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, hyper-v, windows-11

When using VMWare Workstation 16.2, if we try to create Windows VM, we get the following error when starting the Virtual Machine.

> VMware Workstation unrecoverable error: (vcpu-0)
>
> Exception 0xc0000005 (access violation) has occurred.
>
> A log file is available in "C:\Users\name\Documents\Virtual
> Machines\Windows_Server_2019\vmware.log".
>
> You can request support.
>
> To collect data to submit to VMware support, choose "Collect Support
> Data" from the Help menu.
>
> You can also run the "vm-support" script in the Workstation folder
> directly.
>
> We will respond on the basis of your support entitlement.

There are no official communication from VMWare at this moment.

Answer (score 4):

This issue appears to be caused by the setting that allows VMWare to work alongside Hyper-V. There are two fixes, if you want to use Hyper-V along with your VMWare solution, we need to set the core count and processor count to 1.
[image]

This should solve the issues, but this isn't ideal.

The other option is to disable Hyper-V. I came across this when I was trying to run Faceit-AntiCheat Client. It needs Hyper-V to be disabled. If we follow the following steps we can disable Hyper-V and the VM should work fine.

1. Click Start and search for Command Prompt
2. Right-click on Command Prompt and then click Run as administrator
3. If the User Account Control dialog box appears, confirm that the action it displays is what you want, and then click Continue
4. Then type: ***"bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off"*** Press enter
5. Then type:reg add ***"HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceGuard\Scenarios\HypervisorEnforcedCodeIntegrity" /v "Enabled" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f*** Press enter again.
6. Restart your computer

Now you should be able to start the VM with the desired number of processors.

Comment: Deactivating the hyervisor via "bcdedit" and "reg add" solved the issue for me.

Comment: I want to thank iammainul for this post. It fixed my issue first try.
I'm using an Acer Nitro 5 AN517-55  with Windows 11 Pro.
I'm also using VMware Workstation v15.5.7

Comment: You can also disable Hyper-V from the control panel like explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/application-management/virtualization-apps-not-work-with-hyper-v

Answer (score 0):

I did not get the same results.
I ran the bcdedit and reg add with confirmation that it "worked", it did not. I also set the processor to 1/1 after reset.
VMWare 16.2 Windows 10 and Windows Server 2019 clients (both updated and working on another system with NVIDA graphics card
specs below

[System Summary]

Item    Value
OS Name Microsoft Windows 11 Pro
Version 10.0.22000 Build 22000
Other OS Description    Not Available
OS Manufacturer Microsoft Corporation
System Manufacturer Dell Inc.
System Model    Precision 7560
System Type x64-based PC
System SKU  0A69
Processor   11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-11850H @ 2.50GHz, 2496 Mhz, 8 Core(s), 16 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date   Dell Inc. 1.7.0, 12/10/2021
SMBIOS Version  3.2
Embedded Controller Version 255.255
BIOS Mode   UEFI
BaseBoard Manufacturer  Dell Inc.
BaseBoard Product   03DXD2
BaseBoard Version   A00
Platform Role   Mobile
Secure Boot State   Off
PCR7 Configuration  Elevation Required to View
Windows Directory   C:\Windows
System Directory    C:\Windows\system32
Boot Device \Device\HarddiskVolume3
Locale  United States
Hardware Abstraction Layer  Version = "10.0.22000.1"
User Name   BAE0004233\GXP
Time Zone   US Mountain Standard Time
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 32.0 GB
Total Physical Memory   31.2 GB
Available Physical Memory   23.2 GB
Total Virtual Memory    36.2 GB
Available Virtual Memory    25.9 GB
Page File Space 5.00 GB
Page File   C:\pagefile.sys
Kernel DMA Protection   Off
Virtualization-based security   Running
Virtualization-based security Required Security Properties
Virtualization-based security Available Security Properties Base Virtualization Support, DMA Protection, UEFI Code Readonly, SMM Security Mitigations 1.0, Mode Based Execution Control, APIC Virtualization
Virtualization-based security Services Configured   Hypervisor enforced Code Integrity
Virtualization-based security Services Running  Hypervisor enforced Code Integrity
Windows Defender Application Control policy Enforced
Windows Defender Application Control user mode policy   Off
Device Encryption Support   Elevation Required to View
A hypervisor has been detected. Features required for Hyper-V will not be displayed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).